# How to get the extended file attributes from a file, without opening the file

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, xattr

My partner and I have been smashing out heads agaisnt the wall for a while on this. We need to get a look at a files extended file attributes to check for a flag we have placed in there. To do this we believe we need the dentry of the file, we cannot figure out how to get this. We have a valid a Inode and filepath. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this question about **kernel way** for obtaining xattr? If so, the duplicate question doesn't fit that purpose, as it asks about *user space* way.

Comment: Yes it is about kernel space, thanks for catching that!